# Install Zend Framework 3 in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: apt, 16.04, zendframework

I want to install Zend Framework 3 in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial from terminal.
In former versions we used to type:

```
sudo apt-get install zend-framework
```

I am positive the new version has got more commands.

Comment: `apt-get` should still work, although it suggests to use just `apt`. What is the output of the command you issued? Can you paste it [into your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/832446/edit)?

Comment: Thank you, I went to zend frame work 3, the command  for terminal is all there and everything has been working fine so far.

Comment: OK, so please consider [answering your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) or [deleting it](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-questions).